# Is it possible to add two fields with the same name in one table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm developing an ERP for school, every user have his own privilege.

The problem in brief, There are 3 tables

the first is called "users"

- user_id
- username
- password

The second is called "subjects"

- subject_id
- subject_name
- subject_content

The third is called "subject_requests"

- request_id
- date_added
- is_confirmed
- user_id (FK)

A teacher is a USER who can request to add subject_request

A supervisor is a USER who confirm subject_requests

Every one of them is a user who have user_id 
one make a request and another confirm it

Is it right to add 2 fields, user_id AND user_id. 
One for requester and the other for the confirmer?

Comment: instead of adding two user_id columns in 1 table for checking requestor or confirmer you can add a boolean column like is_requestor and if that is 1 than the row is for a requestor else for a confirmer

Comment: it worked for me, thanks @DhavalChheda

Comment: As a better solution, please note that the best approach is to use INNER JOIN instead. Have a Role defined in the users table and then use SQL INNER JOIN to know what is the User's role. Keeping the code to minimum and DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) should be your approach.

Comment: You need to differentiate: `requestor_user_id` and `confirmer_user_id` or something like that. Column names *must* be unique within the table. How else could you distinguish between them otherwise? Always consider the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) when designing your schema. If this isn't a strict 1:1 relationship, a role-based table might be necessary.

Comment: @tadman This is SQL. No bad idea turned away. Just because you can't refer to something doesn't mean you can't have them. Eg duplicate rows. Although sometimes you can refer to them, eg group or sort by column number. A base or temporary table or view can't have two columns with the same name. But a (sub)select value can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add two columns with the same name to a single table. The solution is to include each user_id's role in the column name, e.g. `requesting_user_id` and `confirming_user_id`.